# Binding to a property throws exception

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I wanna bind to my `Patients` static property that can be found on static `DatabaseService` class. Doing so throws an excetion.

```
namespace MyProject.Database{
    static class DatabaseService{
        private static ObservableCollection<Patient> _patients;
        public static ObservableCollection<Patient> Patients {
            get {
                return _patients;
            }
            set {
                if(_patients != value) {
                    _patients = value;
                    StaticPropertyChanged(null,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Patients"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I bind to the list

```
<Controls:FilterableComboBox xmlns:db="clr-namespace:MyProject.Database" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(db:DatabaseService.Patients)}"/>

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll ("Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.")
```

When I try to bind to a different property it works without a problem, just renaming the `Patients` property fixes the problem. Are there some name clashes that I should be wary of?

For instance there is a namespace `MyProject.Patients`

**EDIT:** `DatabaseService` is in `MyProject.Database` namespace, when I try to bind to the same on a class that exists within `MyProject.Patients` namespace it works with no issue

```
namespace MyProject.Patients{
    class X{
        private static ObservableCollection<Patient> _patients;
        public static ObservableCollection<Patient> Patients {
            get {
                return _patients;
            }
            set {
                if(_patients != value) {
                    _patients = value;
                    StaticPropertyChanged(null,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Patients"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With markup like following

```
<Controls:FilterableComboBox xmlns:pt="clr-namespace:MyProject.Patients" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(pt:X.Patients)}"/>
```

**SOLVED:** The problem was that my event `PatientsChanged` existed on the class, however `XXXChanged` is the second version of how to bind to static properties, so data binding thought it should subscribe to the event, however, the event type was not matching the expected one and hence threw an exception

Comment: For instance there is a namespace MyProject.Patients - By this statement do you mean to say that, this namespace exists within your solution OR are you intending to ask if there could be any clash & the namespace is one possible example of the clash?

Comment: I'm intending to ask if it's one possible example of the clash. It's really weird that just changing name of the property makes the problem go away. If I rename `Patients` to Patientss everything works as expected

Comment: Does your solution have a namespace ending with Patients (like this - *.Patients)? If there is any such namespace, that possibly might be the reason for the exception. I come to this conclusion since you mentioned that renaming the property fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes. `MyProject.Patients` is the one

Comment: In the DatabaseService class, have you included a using statement to the MyProject (like this - using MyProject;)?

Comment: I did not have it there as it wasn't required. Tried adding it, but it made no difference. P.S: Editted the post for more clarity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91364/discussion-between-ankit-and-pikausp).